# start sshd on mac

Tags: ssh, osx, sshd, macintosh

I'm not able to ssh to localhost on my Mac. I found that sshd is not running in the machine (no process is running on port 22).

```
lsof -i:22
```

I found some posts asking to enable `Remote Login` in `System Preferences -> Sharing`. Eventhough it is enabled, I'm not able to ssh to localhost. The error I'm getting is this

```
$ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/gkumar6/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/gkumar6/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/gkumar6/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/gkumar6/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/gkumar6/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/gkumar6/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/gkumar6/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/gkumar6/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: It seems like your client is trying to load a bunch of keys and then failing. What does your `~/.ssh/config` look like? You can either create a key (`ssh-keygen`) and put it in your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` or you can tweak your config to allow password login.

Comment: There is no `~/.ssh/config` file in my system. How can I use it allow password login?

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please post the solution as an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: Added the solution as answer.

Comment: To explain why you're not seeing `sshd` running on the Mac (server) side. On Mac OS-X `sshd` is not running `standalone` (i.e. as a long-lived independent service). Instead it is started on-demand by `launchd` when the 'Sharing'  -> 'Remote Login' service is enabled, and an incoming connection is made from a client to the `sshd` port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution for this

I tried to run the `sshd` process manually listening to a different port to debug the issue.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222
```

It showed the actual problem.

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.6, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:oECJtUeeA3sNrAQj3phBiuWJoVl00dzLiXi20tlWF/o
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:uVnKrOK+4V+y3QalyFdqDz+9eBN4oi2E3wb1MDBcgzc
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:CWapRrGUSJx2doJkDf2YR/aZy4BJ4j9K1/ZwX4eUZcg
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:sjzAks0Hud+Ah941pd8ZRNO6MWENdhO8wW4NMNDL2Ns
/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.
```

The permissions to the directory `/var/empty` were

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 gkumar6       sys            224B Aug 12 21:02 empty
```

So I've changed it to `sudo chown root:wheel /var/empty`

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 root          wheel          224B Aug 12 21:02 empty
```

This has solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

The log you are posting is showing that the secure shell daemon *is* running:

```
debug1: Connection established.
```

You would not see that line were it not; would instead see a more succinct log ending with `Connection refused`.

You are not seeing any output from `lsof` most likely because you are not running the command with sufficient privileges:

```
$ lsof -i:22
$ echo $?
1
$ sudo lsof -i:22
sudo lsof -i:22
Password:
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd   1 root   12u  IPv6 0x2feb0cecf91e551b      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   16u  IPv4 0x2feb0cecf91ec3a3      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   22u  IPv6 0x2feb0cecf91e551b      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd   1 root   23u  IPv4 0x2feb0cecf91ec3a3      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

The `echo` statement preceding the second attempt is showing that the previous command returned an exit code of `1`, indicating an error state.

Comment: You are correct. The `sshd` process is running. But do you know why I'm not able to connect to `localhost` via `ssh`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded sshd?

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Comment: Yes, but still not able to `ssh` to `localhost`